# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 502 Bad Gateway nginx error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-502

I am getting a 502 Gad Gateway nginx error returned from a couple of my applications to one single workstation which happens to be an Amazon Workspace workstation. These applications work flawlessly when accessing them from any other machine - including from a different Amazon Workspace. I can see the server side error being returned in the /var/log/nginx/access.log. I have another application that is set up pretty much identically that I can access fine from the Workspace in question. The 502 Bad Gateway shows up only after 4 or 5 minutes of loading. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check any EB logs? Probably you have some wrong ports somewhere.

Comment: Fixed now. Was a bug in the code. thanks.